# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Получаю ошибку:

```
04-17 19:56:04.729 6449-6449/com.vlsoft.design2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vlsoft.design2, PID: 6449
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.vlsoft.design2.fragment.ClassesFragment.initViews(ClassesFragment.java:49)
    at com.vlsoft.design2.fragment.ClassesFragment.onCreateView(ClassesFragment.java:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2595)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
```

в таком фрагменте для вывода списка с секциями

```
public class ClassesFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private List<ListData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClassesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classes, container, false);

        initViews();
        prepareContent();
        setAdapter();
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews() {
        listView = listView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    }

    private void prepareContent() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 6 || i == 11) {
                ListSection listSection = new ListSection();
                listSection.setTitle("Заголовок: " + i);
                dataList.add(listSection);
            } else {
                ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
                listItem.setMessage(i + "-е значение");
                listItem.setMessageLine2(i + "-е значение 2-я строка");
                listItem.setMessageLine3(i + "-е значение 3-я строка");
                dataList.add(listItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        SectionedBaseAdapter adapter =
                new SectionedBaseAdapter(ClassesFragment.this, dataList);
        listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
    }
}
```

В активности аналогичный код со списком работает.
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема вот в этом методе:

```
private void initViews() {
    listView = listView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
}
```

У Вас, очевидно, попытка инициализировать объект через себя самого. В действительности, должно быть так:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classes, container, false);

    initViews(view);
    prepareContent();
    setAdapter();
    return view;
}

private void initViews(View view) {
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
}
```

Comment: В этом случае получаем  ошибку   Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' и после Quick Fixes получаем listView = listView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

Comment: @Vlad.Sh тогда добавьте в вопрос свою верстку, там что-то намудрили скорее всего)

Comment: @Vlad.Sh исправил ответ, разметка тут ни при чем. Просто `findViewById` нужно же вызывать у объекта класса `View`, как раз того, который Вы создаете в `onCreateView`. Очень давно не использовал его (почти два года как пишу на котлине, там есть удобней инструменты), вот и забыл такой момент)

Comment: @Vlad.Sh ну что, у Вас получилось?

Comment: Да, как раз сейчас в процессе.  Ваша правка помогла. Спасибо. Ошибка null object reference исправлена. Появилась следующая: .SectionedBaseAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter. Разбираюсь...